# Trouble starting a Mezzanine/Cartridge project on an Ubuntu VPS

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, mezzanine, cartridge

I keep getting the same Traceback error when trying to start a new Mezzanine project with Cartridge on an Ubuntu VPS:

[image]

It looks like Mezzanine cannot find Cartridge, but I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like permission issue to me. You do not have write privilege on '/projects/mezzanine/jess_site'

You can either work as a root user, which I do not suggest or use '~/projects/mezzanine/jess_site' rather than '/projects/mezzanine/jess_site'.

As you might already know, ~ refers to the home directory which you have read/write permission.